# integrate between curves

Tags: matlab, area, numerical-integration

Here is a plot with 2 trends on it:

[image]

I want to find the area under the black curve (the black lines are all part of one trend), but above the blue curve.

```
%w = wavelength array, Tf = filter Transmission, Ts = spectrum Transmission
figure
plot(w,Tf,'b')
hold on
plot(w,Ts,'k')
```

Comment: I would say spontaneously: `dT = max(Tf,Ts)-Tf;` For quadratur you can use e.g. trapez rule then: `area = sum(diff(w) .* (dT(1:end-1) + dT(2:end)))/2;`

Comment: @matheburg My brain is fried today. You had the solution, but `trapz` does the second half.  :)

Comment: @chappjc in `trapz.m` you will probably find a line very similar to mine :P

Comment: @matheburg Line 68 to be precise!  ;)  BTW, I'd say post your answer if you feel like it.  It's far more educational.

Comment: @chappjc Ah right :D However, shouldn't we prefer `diff(w(:))' * (dT(1:end-1) + dT(2:end))/2`?

Comment: @chappjc it's ok, one answer is enough for this question :)

Comment: @matheburg More than enough I'd say. The `(:)` is superfluous assuming it's a 1D array, but yeah, it's probably good practice to put it in a column.

Comment: @chappjc shouldn't be superfluous as I perferm matrix multiplication there...

Comment: @matheburg Ha, I'm just gonna stop talking now.  Yes, I quite prefer the inner product computed this way (now that I notice it!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the part of the black line (`Ts`) that lies above the blue line (`Tf`) and integrate (`trapz`):

```
d = max(Ts-Tf,0); % or max(Tf,Ts)-Tf;  % thanks, matheburg!
trapz(w,d)
```

Comment: That is not really the area, it should depend on `w` as well (cf. my comment above).

Comment: @matheburg True!  Answered too hastily.  How about using `trapz` then?  Does that work?

Comment: Should be the same... ;)